# Single Login in multi web applications (Myportal, OpenERP)

Tags: web, authentication, single-sign-on, odoo

This question already existed but there were no answers. We have the same problem. I have a website and an openerpwebsite.

My problem is when the user logins in my website, it should also automatically login in the openerpwebsite when a specific button for openerp is clicked. I have no idea on how to do this. Can anybody help me? please ;(

Answer (score 2):

You should look into SSO (Single Sign On) capabilities. If you are using OpenERP 7, the best is to consider an oauth provider and to use it for your website to get your visitors logged into both systems (just like you have access to GMail when you log into Google Drive for example).

OAuth settings are in Settings > Users > OAuth Providers
You can find more info in the section 4.3 of the release notes: openerp.com/node/1272

If you are using OpenERP 6.1, there is an openid capability with the module auth_openid available here: http://apps.openerp.com/addon/6962

Comment: I am using OpenERP 6.1 so I have to used the auth_openid. However, I guess it is not suitable for a site that has many users, right? My site can only be used if you have an account on it. Is it still possible to use the auth_openid for this kind of site?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole purpose. And it will work independently of the number of users you have.

Comment: how to use auth_openid? i dont know how.